# How to have different pages in php

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I'm, trying to create a simple cms as I learn php and I was wondering what the best way to have different pages would be? So that from the backend the use can add a page which would be separate from the homepage and would get its text from I presume a database.

I'm open to all ways of doing this as i haven't got a clue. If you need more info please comment.

Denver

Comment: what CMS are you using? is that hard coded or you are using some open source CMS software like Drupal, Wordpress, Joomla etc...does are the popular once...

Comment: did you try any existing CMS like `wordpress`, `joomla` and `drupal`?

Comment: i did i'm and they work fine but as i learn php i'm trying to build a cms as a project

Comment: It's a little too general to answer I think.  If this is something you're doing basically as a learning experience, then you might want to look more at how people design large projects.  You should sketch out (on the computer or paper or whiteboard; whatever is most comfortable) what the major components of your CMS will be and how they interact, why they're needed (i.e. what features they support).  It's probably more instructive to invent your own design so you understand fully what the challenges are, and then look at how people have actually done it.

Comment: if this was going to be a production product or if i was starting over i definitely would but I have gotten alot done already. But yes generally i would

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not look at how one of the best-in-class systems do it? The basic principles of databased content and templates tend to work the same way across various CMSs and this would give you a great head-start.

For my money, a good example would be [Silverstripe](http://www.silverstripe.org/introduction/) at this point in time - they have a good clean underlying code structure and some easy-to-follow [tutorials](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/tutorials/) that get the basics across very quickly.

Comment: I've built many myself, but if I were you I'd still be looking at how the "greats" do it - for inspiration if nothing else.